# Error In Deploying "Error writing file FOLDERID_APPID_INSTALL....." at WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, deployment, visual-studio-2013, runtime-error

When I deploy my application to my unlocked device (Lumia 1020), VS is giving me an error that

[image: Error]

I am using VS 2013 and it is in admin mode. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try removing the app and then deploying it? Clean - build solution? Restart VS? Also, when did it start happening, did you do something, install something etc.?

Comment: That usually indicates that you have the same app (or an app with the same guid) on the phone. Usually you have the released version on your phone while trying to install a dev version

Comment: Thank you, its reason was the same product ID with dev version and debug version.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error when trying to deploy a release build to my Lumia 920.

As Shawn Kendrot mentions in the comments, I already had the release build deployed to my phone as installed via the store.

Switching to a debug build and deploying that one instead worked.