# Issues deploying my WP8 app to a WP10 phone for debugging

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to deploy my Cordova app (build target: Windows 8.0 and above) to a Windows 10 phone from Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 8.1.

- Whenever I start VS as an administrator (should be the local administrator account, without any connection to the domain) and deploy from there, my Visual Studio crashes reproducibly.
- When I start VS as myself (domain user with admin rights on my computer), there are three possible outcomes:

  - The first time I deploy, the error is ["The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlock and that the application is installed."](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ac252c9-5353-4d3f-a4f3-ce03d122669e/the-application-could-not-be-launched-for-debugging?forum=wptools)
  - Every subsequent try, I get ["Error writing file %FOLDERID_APPID_INSTALL%...: Access denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132635/error-in-deploying-error-writing-file-folderid-appid-install-at-wp8)
  - If I have deployed for the first time (and any number of subsequent tries), and then started VS as administrator and it crashed, and then I go into VS as a normal user again and try to deploy, it also crashes reproducibly.
  - If I close VS, delete the `.vs` folder and the `MyApp.user` file, and start VS again, I can start over freshly: The next time I deploy it is like the first time again ("could not be launched for debugging") and so on...

Why is this and how can I get my app deployed for debugging?

Comment: I guess the Phone is unlocked for Development? But actually im not sure if it is possible at all to debug Windows 10 Mobile on Windows 8/8.1. Did you try to just Deploy it, without Debugging and start it manually on the Phone then?

Comment: Yes, the phone is unlocked. The app was successfully installed and started, and I could use the app, but I didn't get debug output in the VS output window. I have upgraded to Windows 10 in the meantime, and the problem remains. I am not sure if it is possible at all to debug Windows 8.x apps on a Windows 10 phone...

Comment: Is this just about your Debug output or is it about all the output generated by the app? (Try Console.WriteLine instead of Debug.writeLine/Log)

Comment: It is about all the output generated by the app.

Comment: Okay. But the connection between VS and the App is still alive (You can Stop/Break/Restart your App in VS)?

Comment: And your Output Window is empty?

Comment: I cannot start/stop/break/restart the app from VS. When I try to start, it is installed and the error is "The application could not be launched...". I can select the app from the phone's app list, that's it. So VS installs it correctly, but cannot start it. The VS output window is empty when I start the app from the phone's app list (of course).